# Haskell: head . mergeSort (for min element) in linear time?

Tags: sorting, haskell, lazy-evaluation, mergesort

In the HaskellWiki https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/Laziness they introduce the merge-sort function as non-lazy

```
merge_sort []  = []
merge_sort [x] = [x]
merge_sort lst = let (e,o) = cleave lst 
              in merge (merge_sort e) (merge_sort o) where
 merge :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
 merge xs [] = xs
 merge [] ys = ys
 merge xs@(x:t) ys@(y:u)
     | x <= y    = x : merge t ys
     | otherwise = y : merge xs u
```

since you first have to recursively cleave the list

```
 cleave = cleave' ([],[]) where
 cleave' (eacc,oacc) [] = (eacc,oacc)
 cleave' (eacc,oacc) [x] = (x:eacc,oacc)
 cleave' (eacc,oacc) (x:x':xs) = cleave' (x:eacc,x':oacc) xs
```

and then, going up the reduction layers, merge these. So a merge-sort runs in n(log n) time. But the composition

```
min xs = head . merge_sort $ xs
```

supposedly runs in linear time. I can't see why, as you still have to cleave every sublist until you arrive at the singleton/empty lists and then merge these to guarantee the first element of the returned list is the smallest of all. What am I missing?

Comment: As that wiki page explains, that implementation of `cleave` is insufficiently lazy to write an optimal incremental merge sort.

Comment: you are missing that with the overly strict `cleave` as in your question,   `head . mergesort` will build an implicit fully sorted tree before producing the head element, just as you expected; but with the other version on that page it would build an implicit _heap_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But lazyness still comes into play with the definitions like min xs = head . merge_sort $ xs. In finding the minimal element this way **only the necessary amount of comparisons** between elements will be performed (O(n) a.o.t. O(nlogn) comparisons needed to fully sort the whole list).

You are right, it will have a time complexity of *O(n log(n))*, however if you read the above paragraph carefully you will see, that it is talking about the amount of comparisons. Only *O(n)* comparisions will be performed, because every `merge` application only has to produce one element, so it only has to compare the first two elements of its arguments. So you get *n/2* comparisons at the leaves of the recursion plus *n/4* one level up, then *n/4*,... all the way up to the top-level of the recursion. If you work it out you get *n-1* comparisons.

Comment: The OP's implementation of `cleave` looks like the problem. It's unnecessarily strict.

Comment: IOW the _time complexity_ with the properly lazy version of `cleave` is *O(n)*.